# How to executed if statement that checks the exit status from a function in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a function that checks the exit status of an executed Linux command and echos if the command failed to execute or it executed correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

check_command(){

if [$? -eq 0]
then
  echo "Command Executed"
else
  echo "Command Failed"
fi

}

ls -la
check_command()
```

When I run this bash script I get the following error.

```
test_command.sh: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What code is needed to be able to execute the script correctly with no errors?

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basic formatting errors and you fail to pass the exit condition to the `check_command()` function to compare against `0`.

- You need a space around the side of the arguments to `[ ... ]`, e.g. `[ "$1" -eq 0 ]` (note: always quote variables within `[ ... ]`
- You must pass the exit condition as an argument to the function, e.g. call your command and then pass `$?` as an argument to `check_command()`, e.g.

```bash
ls -la > /dev/null
check_command $?
```

(**note:** when calling the function you do NOT include `()` at the end)

and then your first positional parameter to your function `$1` will contain the exit condition, e.g.

```bash
check_command(){
  
  if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]
  then
    ...
```

Putting it altogether you can do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

check_command(){
  
  if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Command Executed"
  else
    echo "Command Failed"
  fi

}

ls -la > /dev/null
check_command $?
```

(note: redirection to `/dev/null` added to suppress the `ls -al` output, remove if desired)

For most commands there is no need to write a function to check the exit status. You can simply use `||` to create an compound-command where the utility itself will write the error to `stderr` and you can exit (or handle the failure any way you like), e.g.

```bash
ls -la || {
  echo "Command Failed" >&2
  exit 1
}
```

If you want to do something when a command succeeds, you can use `command && cmd_on_success`.

If you paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) it will find any syntax and script issues present. That give you a very good way to resolve simple issues.